# crop all images within a directory

Tags: php

I want to modify the code below to include multiple images for cropping. Can you give me hints how to start out? Thank you

```
<?php       
function PIPHP_ImageCrop($image, $x, $y, $w, $h)
{
          $tw = imagesx($image);
          $th = imagesy($image);
          if ($x > $tw || $y > $th || $w > $tw || $h > $th)
                      return FALSE;
          $temp = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
          imagecopyresampled($temp, $image, 0, 0, $x, $y, 
                      $w, $h, $w, $h);
           return $temp;
}


           $image = imagecreatefrompng("/Users/Anay/Desktop/DESKTOP/testimage.png");
           $copy = PIPHP_ImageCrop($image, 0, 0, 656, 1240);
           if (!$copy) echo "Crop failed: Argument(s) out of bounds";
           else imagepng($copy, "photo8.jpg");

?>
```

Comment: Loop through directory, scan images & call your function to crop them. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591851/php-html-how-to-loop-through-a-directory-with-images) may helps you to get a direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP **scandir** function (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) for get all files in a directory. Loop all files with **foreach** and if file an image, you can use your crop function to crop image.