# how to load local files inot a div from a menu of many html doc links

Tags: html, jquery, load, offline, megamenu

I have a note taking system I have used with students using frames.  Going to flexbox using jquery.  This system has more than 1000 files for notes for each class (as in school).  Is there a way to write a jquery command that loads based based on "html" rather than write out each link individually.  My menu is a pure css ul li setup.  The note system is run offline. Flexbox with jquery has my head spinning for more than 6  months.  Before I try to learn how to load a huge menu and files (more than 2 gb) online for folks to see, is this possible?
Please be kind, I am a teacher who is trying to make solutions to help students, not a programmer.

Comment: Just saw I should say I can load into a new tab but not into the same page as the menu into a content div

Answer (score 0):

We need to know more about your configuration/setup in order to best answer your question.

First, we would need to know how to get a list of files from where they are stored. Are you using a LAMP stack? (WAMP or MAMP or XAMP?) Where are the files stored, and how does WordPress access them (assuming megamenu refers to the the WordPress add-on?)?

Usually, you can get a list of files in a folder using a server-side language like PHP or NodeJS. For PHP, you need to be using a LAMP stack (that's what the P stands for). WordPress sites generally use PHP - and if you are running it offline then you probably are using a LAMP stack - but we need to know that.

Also, jQuery has a [`$.load()` command](https://api.jquery.com/load/) that allows you to load the contents of a file into a div (or other HTML container). Logic-wise, you could loop through all files in the folder via PHP and output an HTML table containing an `a` tag for each file, that, when clicked either opens that file or (using $.load()) reads the file and puts the contents into another div on the page.

Assuming a PHP back end, here are some resources that will show you how to get a list of all the files in a folder, loop through them, and output some HTML:

[List all files in one directory PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774669/list-all-files-in-one-directory-php)

[PHP script to loop through all of the files in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202175/php-script-to-loop-through-all-of-the-files-in-a-directory)

[Loop through all images in folder, output HTML to display image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11591963/1447509)

[Full basic course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWG7ajC_OVo&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gksOX3Kd9KPo-O68ncT05o&pp=iAQB) for learning PHP (excellent and fast-paced):